# Does arithmetic go back before 2000 BC

Tags: mathematics, arithmetic

There are various documents stating that arithmetic was first seen in 2000 BC, but wondered whether if there were any signs of it before?

Comment: Please define "sign". Do you mean written sources (e.g. sample problems like those in the Rhind papyrus)? For example, the Great Pyramid dates to about 2600 BC, and one might reasonably hypothesize that it could not have been built without the help of arithmetic. Does that count as a "sign"? Also, please indicate in more detail what your research has revealed so far.